# Print images respecting scaling in RTFs

Tags: image, scale, rtf

I've got an RTF file with an embedded image in it. The image is scaled by 2/3, or 0.67. It displays correctly in Word, but when the file is printed it consistently displays by ignoring the scale setting.

The source image is a PNG with dimensions 297x117 (pixels). The image was originally encoded as follows:

```
{\pict\pngblip\picw7858\pich3096\picwgoal4455\pichgoal1755\picscalex67\picscaley67
 <Hex-encoded PNG image>}
```

The original picture width/height is calculated as `(w,h) * 2.54 * 1000 / 96` (twips).

The original picture width/height **goal** is calculated as `(w,h) * 1440 / 96` (twips).

A twip is 1/1440 inch and 2.54 is the number of centimetres in an inch.

I edited it to try setting the size manually. I multiplied all of these values by 2/3 and removed the `\picscale[xy]67` instructions:

```
{\pict\pngblip\picw5239\pich2064\picwgoal2985\pichgoal1176
 <Hex-encoded PNG image>}
```

However, it still seems to only use the size of the PNG (297x117) when printing it. The screen display and the print result both appear unchanged from before.

Other than manually rescaling the image and re-embedding it into the RTF, can I get the printed version to respect the scaling?

---

#### UPDATE

I did try embedding an image resized to 2/3 of the previous dimensions, but the printed image is still 50% larger than the on-screen image (the extra area gets cropped). The only difference is that it was much lower resolution.

I also tried the same image in a Word document and it printed perfectly, so it's definitely a difference between `.docx` and `.rtf` files. Is it perhaps a dpi setting in the PNG image?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 updated itself last night, and now I can't replicate the problem. All old files that previously had this problem, no longer have this problem. Go Microsoft!

It appears to be this update that resolved the issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4093112/windows-10-update-kb4093112

> **Addresses an issue with printing content generated by ActiveX in Internet Explorer**

There's no more information about this, but it is related to printing.